# Yii2: Display GET params in url on the index page using ActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I use ActiveDataProvider and Gridview in my site. Get parameters appear in url only after searching for some field (they are missing on the index page when the site first loads).

How can I by default add some GET parameters in url when first loading the index page has not yet been searched.

Comment: Gridview page url is called from other webpage. So add get parameters when gridview page url is composed, otherwise define some default value for missing get parameters, in gridview page.

Comment: Yii::$app->request->setQueryParams([
            'MySearch' => [
                'name' => 'John',
                'email' => 'john@test.com',
            ]
        ]);

In this way?

Comment: Why do you need to forge query params ? Can't you define default values for missing parameters?

Comment: I can not find how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your action is called "mySearch", here an example to use a default value if parameters is missing:

```
public function actionMySearch()
{
     // Flat php
     $mySearchName = isset($_GET['MySearch']['name']) ? $_GET['MySearch']['name'] :'John';
     $mySearchEmail = isset($_GET['MySearch']['email']) ? $_GET['MySearch']['email'] : 'john@test.com';

     // Yii helpers
     $mySearchName = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getValue($_GET, 'MySearch.name', 'John');
     $mySearchEmail = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getValue($_GET, 'MySearch.email', 'john@test.com');
}
```